# Post Request Routing Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I would like to tell a route to get the post request from a form. The post request looks like this:

```
/product/dashboard?from=2013-09-17&to=2013-09-17
```

My Route looks like this:

```
Route::post('/product/dashboard', function()
    {
        $from = Input::get('from');
        $from = Input::get('to');
        return $from;
    });
```

What am I doing wrong or what should I do differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way RESTful urls work in Laravel 4:

```
Route::post('/product/dashboard/{from}/{to?}', function($from, $to = "")
    {
        return "$from $to";
    });
```

And your request should be:

```
/product/dashboard/2013-09-17/2013-09-17
```

Or just

```
/product/dashboard/2013-09-17
```